# ¿Es posible usar flexbox para que ocupe el espacio entre contenedores?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Este es mi problema, antes usaba "column-gaps:6;" para que me permita hacer esto, pero cada vez que cargaban mas posts, se desordenaban, y aun poniendo "position:absolute" o algun otro atributo, no se solucionaba
Asi que probe flexbox, el cual funciono, sin embargo no quedo de la misma forma:

Ej (Ilustracion):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CSS:

```
.posts-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 100%;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.posts-container .post-container {
    width: 175px;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    background-color: #463E3F;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="posts-container" id="posts-container">
   <div class="post-container"></div>
   <div class="post-container"></div>
   <div class="post-container"></div>
   <div class="post-container"></div>
   <div class="post-container"></div>
   <div class="post-container"></div>
   <div class="post-container"></div>
   <div class="post-container"></div>
</div>
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si lo que buscas es generar un espacio entre y al rededor de los flex-items entonces ¿no ayuda un margin aplicado a todos los elementos con la misma medida?

Comment: @BetaM Ya esta aplicado el margin, sin embargo el flexbox no me deja hacer ese efecto, aunque use el "align-items:flex-start", la proxima row de posts, comienza donde termina el mas grande de la primera

Comment: Ok es que la pregunta es confusa, entonces la duda es como lograr un diseño como el de la imagen manteniendo flexbox?

Comment: @RadioAF Esto te puede servir: https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb

Comment: @BetaM Asi mismo...Con el column-gap que aplicaba antes con un display:block; me funcionaba para que se vea asi, solo que cuando llegabas al fondo de la pagina y se cargaban nuevos posts, se mezclaban todos nuevamente

Comment: @UrielManzano Muchas gracias! Estuve mirando un poco, no hay forma de hacerlo únicamente con css?

Comment: @RadioAF agregue una respuesta, no lo adapte a tu avance actual por el tiempo, espero te sirva.

Comment: @UrielManzano Muchas gracias, me sirvió para entender un poco mejor, sin embargo no me funciono bien, no se si por como ubique cada atributo o como, pero gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si no te causa problemas cambiar el código podrias revisar esta implementación.

Referencia: [Tablero responsivo](https://www.cssscript.com/css-pinterest-like-responsive-board-layout-boardz-css/)
Ejemplos: [Ejemplos tableros responsivos](https://www.cssscript.com/demo/css-pinterest-like-responsive-board-layout-boardz-css/)

```css
.boardz {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex: auto;
}
.boardz ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
    flex: 1;
}
.boardz ul li {
    margin: 8px 4px 8px 4px;
    padding: 12px;
    flex: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #737373;
}
.boardz ul h1 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .boardz {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .boardz ul li:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .boardz ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
.fitted ul {
    display: flex;
}
.fitted ul li {
    margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px !important;
}
.boardz img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.beautiful li {
    border: none !important;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}
.beautiful li:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
.centered-block {
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="boardz centered-block">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <img src="https://kingofwallpapers.com/poster/poster-003.jpg" alt="demo image"/>
      </li>

      <li>
          <img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-pINYV0WlFyA/VUK-QcGbU5I/AAAAAAAABcU/fNy2pd2cFRk/s1600/WEB-Jack-White-Poster-Creative.png" alt="demo image"/>
      </li>

      <li>
          <img src="https://payload140.cargocollective.com/1/10/349041/5110553/Florrie.jpg" alt="demo image"/>
      </li>                    
  </ul>
  <ul>
      <li>
          <img src="https://cdn3.volusion.com/prakm.mcyzp/v/vspfiles/photos/TWAMBLUE-2.jpg" alt="demo image"/>
      </li>
      <li>
          <img src="https://wpmedia.ottawacitizen.com/2015/11/01.jpg?quality=55&strip=all&w=840&h=630&crop=1" alt="demo image"/>
      </li>
      <li>
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8c/ee/ff/8ceeff967c03c7cf4f86391dd6366544.jpg" alt="demo image"/>
      </li>
      <li>
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/87/16/8c/87168cbbf07cb54a9793bebaa20b1bde.jpg" alt="demo image"/>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
      <li>
          <img src="https://images.fromupnorth.com/077/54a12d7458673.jpg" alt="demo image"/>
      </li>
      <li>
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/22/95/48/229548086245c332443109ca9f2e0890.jpg" alt="demo image"/>
      </li>
      <li>
          <img src="https://inspirationfeeed.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/ca402f7410884454ec5c303336e8591d1.jpg" alt="demo image"/>
      </li>
  </ul>         
</div>
```